# fscommand AS2.0: Unable to run rstrui and sfc scan from flash exe file

Tags: fscommand

I have 4 batch files (1.bat, 2.bat, 3.bat, & 4.bat) that are linked to Shortcuts (msinfo32.lnk, rstrui.lnk, chkdsk.lnk, &sfcscan.lnk) correspondingly. These shortcuts are set to open another set of bat files (msinfo32.bat, rstrui.bat, chkdsk.bat, & sfcscan.bat) as Admin.

1 & 3 works fine (msinfo32 & chkdsk), but I can't make 2 & 4(rstrui & sfc) to run their corresponding programs. I can run all of them just fine if I don't go through the Flash Projected file.

Error for rstrui: 'rstrui.exe'is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Error for sfc scan: Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.

***Emphasis: No problem with going through the files directly. Problem only appears when using them through the flash exe file.***

I'm using Flash CS6 on AS 2.0. I'm trying to create a Flash (EXE) file that can run these functions using buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me with sfc. Only happens after converting batch to exe.

I found solution here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/81883/

Answered by Mohammad Nazari

> I found the answer myself:
>   I created a project that compiled by 32bit compiler but my windows7 platform was 64bit and this did not work.
>   After that, I test this project in windows7 32bit and was OK. and I created project with 64bit compiler in windows7 64bit and that was OK too.